# Ffmpeg support for svg rasterization

Tags: svg, ffmpeg

FFmpeg now support librsvg support for SVG rasterization.

I have tried the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i test.svg test.png
```

But I get the following error:

```
Decoder (codec svg) not found for input stream #0:0
```

I have search the doc but there is no examples given. Can someone tell me how to a command line using ffmpeg to generate a PNG from a SVG file?

Answer (score 12):

Your ffmpeg needs to be compiled with `--enable-librsvg`. If you're compiling ffmpeg then you need to install whatever package provides the librsvg header files. For example, in Arch Linux it is *librsvg*, and in Ubuntu it is *librsvg2-dev*.

## Series of images

Usage is similar to using raster images as inputs with the [image demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1). For example, a series of images named `vector-001.svg`, `vector-002.svg`, `vector-003.svg`, etc:

```
ffmpeg -i vector-%03d.svg -vf format=yuv420p output.mp4
```

## Single image

```
ffmpeg -i input.svg output.png
```

#### With custom size:

```
ffmpeg -width 600 -i input.svg output.png
```

`-keep_ar true` is the default, so it will automatically calculate height in this example to preserve the aspect ratio.

## Decoder specific options

The decoder librsvg has a few input options:

```
$ ffmpeg -h decoder=librsvg
  […]
  -width             <int>        .D.V...... Custom width to render to (0 for default) (from 0 to INT_MAX) (default 0)
  -height            <int>        .D.V...... Custom height to render to (0 for default) (from 0 to INT_MAX) (default 0)
  -keep_ar           <boolean>    .D.V...... Keep aspect ratio with custom width/height (default true)
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer --enable-librsvg does not appear in configuration by default. It has been a while since I have compile anything on window but will give it a go.
Would you happen to have a compile version for window with --enable-librsvg enabled so I can give it a try? 
I just want to see whether it is  actually possbile to create an Mp4 video with a serie of SVG as input.

Comment: Hello, I have finally compiled ffmpeg on Window with --enable-librsvg as you suggested. And I was able to convert a set of Svg to an Mp4 which is really cool.
Thanks a lot for your precious advice LordNeckbeard!

Comment: I'm having trouble compiling FFmpeg with --enable-librsvg on windows 10 64. Any suggestion of a tutorial to follow or the method that worked for you?

Comment: @AhmedHawary Sorry, but I'm not a Windows user. Maybe https://github.com/rdp/ffmpeg-windows-build-helpers can help.

Comment: @Olivier Etienne could you be so kind as to link your build or the instructions you used?